# Azure offline sync of data from 1:n relationship in Android mobile app

Tags: java, c#, android, azure

I'm trying to enable Azure offline sync in my Android app (Java). I added models with 1:n relationship to my cloud sync web service (C#) like in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/27/retrieving-data-from-1n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services/) article:

```
public class TodoItem : EntityData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

But how can I set 1:n relationship in Java code in my client application?

```
public class TodoItem {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    private String mId;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("text")
    private String mText; 
}
```

Is it possible to implement table relationships (either server side or client side) in Azure offline sync? Did someone make it?

If yes, how MobileServiceSyncContext resolves order of tables during  push process? I mean, if server side (Azure mobile app) supports relationship, and client side (Android application) - doesn't support, and if MobileServiceSyncContext pushes table Item first, data consistency error will occured on server side.

And if Azure Mobile Apps does not support relationships at all (neither server side or client side), that means that my storage doesn't contain related tables, it's just a heap of unrelated tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android client on Azure Mobile Apps, your scenario is belong to store an object with complex properties or array property into a table, please refer to the subsection `How to: Store an object or array property into a table` of the section [`How to: Customize the client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#a-namecustomizingahow-to-customize-the-client) from the Azure offical document to do it.

As reference, there is a [blog](http://hashtagfail.com/post/44606137082/mobile-services-android-serialization-gson) which introduce how to do it.