# Syncing multiple table SQLite android with azure

Tags: java, android, database, azure, sqlite

I have an android app with sqlite database, i want to sync it to Azure database using mobile services. I have multiple tables in my database, the documentation shows one table along with back-end. I do not have backend. I cant work around the documentation.

Can anyone explain in simple words on how to sync multiple tables , I have submission tomorrow

P.S. I am using Java and Android Studio
Edit : So far, I have app with sqlite database to CRUD. I want to implement sync with Azure database multiple tables

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data

Comment: Please keep your question to a specific issue and show what you have attempted thus far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, the `Easy tables` and `Easy APIs` features are enough for your Android app which only has some tables of simple structure, and Azure Mobile Apps itself is the backend. You can refer to the related sections of `Easy tables` and `Easy APIs` from these documents below.

[image]

1. Node.js backend [How to use the Mobile Apps Node.js SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk)
2. .Net backend [Getting Started with Azure Mobile Apps’ Easy Tables](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/)

To explain on how to sync tables, I think the section [`Implement Offline Sync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#offline-sync) of the offical tutorial `How to use the Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android` is good enough.

> The Azure Mobile Apps Client SDK also implements offline synchronization of data by using a SQLite database to store a copy of the server data locally. Operations performed on an offline table do not require mobile connectivity to work. Offline sync aids in resilience and performance at the expense of more complex logic for conflict resolution.

And for syncing tables of simple structure which be mapped to an object, to sync multiple tables is same as to sync one. But for a complex object structure map to multi-table, it need to [call a custom API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#custom-api) defined in the backend that you can refer to my answer for the existing SO thread [Azure offline sync of data from 1:n relationship in Android mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666535/azure-offline-sync-of-data-from-1n-relationship-in-android-mobile-app/41671772#41671772) and this blog [`Episode II: Customizing serialization using the gson library in the Mobile Services Android client`](https://hashtagfail.com/posts/2013/03/04/mobile-services-android-serialization-gson).